# when I type "sudo apt-get update" I get the error?

Tags: apt

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two updating applications open at the same time. This most likely means you have the Software Center or Synaptic open when attempting to use `apt` in the terminal. Close the Software Center and/or Synaptic and it should work.